# How to write $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ in terms of $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to rewrite $$\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ in terms of $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$$
Soo ... I must say
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}=y$$
Then write $x$ in terms of $y$ ,but how?

Comment: Write $x=u^2$ and solve the quadratic equation? [Hint: the final result is $\frac{y^2}{1-2 y^2}$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}=y \iff yx-\sqrt x+y=0 \quad \sqrt x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$

Comment: Gimusi sorry. But I am completely confused!

Comment: @user602338 We can consider  $yx-\sqrt x+y=0$ as a qudratic equation and from here obtain $\sqrt x$. It seems that for any $0<y<\frac12$we have 2 solutions for $\sqrt x$ and one for $y=\frac12$. From $\sqrt x>0$ we can determine $x$ and $x^2$.

Comment: Would you please define $a,b,c$ in this quadratic equation?

Comment: @user602338 What do you think they could be $y\cdot (\sqrt x)^2-1\cdot (\sqrt x)+y=0$?

Comment: Oh yes. That's it! Thanks!  Just one more problem. How did you find range of $y$ and $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @user602338 From the quadratic we see that $1-4y^2\ge 0 \iff -1/2\le y \le 1/2$ but we also need $y\neq 0$ and since $y>0$ (because we need $\sqrt x>0$). Note also that from the quadratic equation we lost the solution $x=y=0$which holds by inspection for the original equation.

Comment: @user602338 You only need to work on that and make a lot of excercise! When you learn a trick, it is important that you keep that in mind and try to use in some other cotext too.

Comment: @user602338 Of course follow your teachers and if you have more time ask them to give you additional exercises to do and material to study.

Comment: @user602338 Do not ask additional questions in comments. Let make another OP with all the nessary context, your work and effort on it. You'll receive of course some help on it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1} = y$$ implies $$y^{-2} = x + 2 + x^{-1},$$ so that $$x + x^{-1} = y^{-2} - 2.$$  But $$\frac{x}{x^2 + 1} = (x + x^{-1})^{-1} = (y^{-2} - 2)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Can you explain first part of your answer please?

Comment: How did you square both sides?

Comment: @user602338 Why don’t you try showing the first step now that you have seen it?  What transformations do you need to apply?

Comment: Ok thanks! I solved the puzzle!

Comment: @user602338 persistence and practice is a big part of learning.  Don’t give up so easily.  As you have now seen, you figured out how to do the first part, so it is not as if you are totally helpless.  You simply need to exercise your skills and your mathematical reasoning will become more sophisticated the more you work at it.